# How to input therefore sign in mathematica

Tags: formatting, symbols

I'm wondering how to input a therefore sign in Mathematica?

For example, I want to input / output something like:

```
∴ a == 2 + 1 // TraditionalForm
∴ a = 3
```

However, I get a syntax error. I'm guessing this is because the `\[Therefore]` is `Therefore[x, y]` that needs two arguments.

Doing `Therefore[None, TraditionalForm[a == 2 + 1]]` just seems to output `None ∴ a == 3`

I don't want to just use a text cell for this purpose, since I would like this to be dynamic.

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: You need it to have "2+1" and not 3?

Comment: No, I do want the 2+1 to be evaluated to 3, if that's what you mean?

Comment: I was going to suggest `Therefore["", TraditionalForm[a == 2 + 1]]` or `Row[{"\[Therefore] ", Dynamic[a], " = ", 2, "+", 1}]`, either may suit your needs

Comment: @JasonB The Therefore["", ...] seems to work, although it is a little messy but I can't find any other way of doing it. Thanks for the help!